# Filter XML based on node value and convert to JSON using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a XML document which I have to filter based on the value of a node and then have to return the matching node's parent along with its all children in JSON format.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <col-name name="col1Name" />
    <col-name name="col2Name" />
    <row>
        <col>Test1</col>
        <col>Test2</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col>Test3</col>
        <col>Test4</col>
    </row>
</root>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        {
            "filtered-result": [
                <xsl:for-each select="//row[col[normalize-space(text()) = 'Test2']]">
                    <xsl:variable name="columnCount" select="count(./*)" />
                    {
                        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                            <xsl:variable name="columnIndex" select="position()" />
                            "<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(//col-name[$columnIndex]/@name)" />": "<xsl:value-of select="." />"<xsl:if test="$columnIndex &lt; $columnCount">,</xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    }<xsl:if test="./following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            ]
        }
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "filtered-result": [

            {

                    "col1Name": "Test1",
                    "col2Name": "Test2"
            }
    ]
}
```

I am using SAXON  as the XSLT processor.

I am getting the results as expected. Is there any other way to get the desired results? Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Saxon are you using? There is some new support for XML to JSON and JSON serialization in XSLT and XPath 3.0/3.1 so you might be able to use that with 9.6 or 9.7, depending on version and edition.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am using `Saxon HE 9.6.0.7`. I have to look into the new features for Xpath 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to simplify your code to

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:key name="col" match="col-name">
        <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:key>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        {
        "filtered-result": [
        <xsl:for-each select="//row[col[normalize-space(.) = 'Test2']]">
            {
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                "<xsl:value-of select="key('col', string(position()))/@name" />": "<xsl:value-of select="." />"<xsl:if test="position() lt last()">,</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            }<xsl:if test="position() lt last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        ]
        }
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Both your solution as well as my attempt at a simplification suffer from the problem that any character in a column that would need escaping in a JSON value, like a double quote `"` would break the output result.

Therefore I think it is better to rely on a conversion that takes such problems into account and escapes any characters as needed.

In XSLT 3.0 with XPath 3.1 support you can construct [maps](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-maps) and [arrays](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-arrays) and you can [serialize them as JSON](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#json-output), here is my attempt to use those features on your problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map array"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="col" match="col-name">
        <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:key>

    <xsl:template match="root"> 
        <xsl:sequence select="map { 'filtered-result' : array:join(row[col = 'Test2']/[map:merge(col/map:entry(key('col', string(position()))/@name, string())) ]) }"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Saxon 9.7 EE, when running that XSLT 3.0 code against the input sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <col-name name="col1Name" />
    <col-name name="col2Name" />
    <row>
        <col>Test1</col>
        <col>Test2</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col>Test3</col>
        <col>Test4</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col>Test5</col>
        <col>Test2"</col>
    </row>
</root>
```

outputs

```
 {
  "filtered-result": [
     {
      "col1Name":"Test1",
      "col2Name":"Test2"
     },
     {
      "col1Name":"Test5",
      "col2Name":"Test2\""
     }
   ]
 }
```

As a third option that also requires XSLT 3.0 but is available in Saxon 9.7 HE you can use the function `xml-to-json` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-xml-to-json) after transforming your XML input to the [input format](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#xml-to-json-transformation) required for that function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="col" match="col-name">
        <xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:integer">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="$index"/>
    </xsl:key>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="json-doc">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-doc, map{ 'indent': true()})"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <map>
            <array key="filtered-results">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="row[col[normalize-space(.) = 'Test2']]"/>
            </array>
        </map>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <map>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </map>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="col">
        <string key="{key('col', position())/@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```